# Transform the std::tuple types to another ones

Tags: c++, generics

Let's say ı have a type traits to transform one type to another one

```
template<typename ...> struct Transforming;
template<typename T> struct Transforming<T> { using type = T; };
template<> struct Transforming<char> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<long> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<double> { using type = float; };
```

So what ı wanted is, ı want to transform the tuple types to another one via the above type traits. ı know ı should variadic templates but ı could not make the algorithm. At the end, ı should have something like this.

```
using TUPLE = tuple<int, float,char, short, double, double>;
using transformed_tuple = transform_types_t<Transforming<>, TUPLE>;
transformed_tuple --> tuple<int, float, int, int, float, float>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you want `tuple<int, float, int, short, float, float>` as an output.

Comment: Are you transforming only types or some actual data? If some data then: which version of C++ you are using? With C++17 auto deduction of return type makes this task trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ templates have a kind of parameter called [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) which is a template parameter which is itself a template. These types of parameters can be used to provide templates like `Transforming<T>`.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/M6b4P4oG7) :

```
#include <tuple>

// Original trait
template<typename ...> struct Transforming;
template<typename T> struct Transforming<T> { using type = T; };
template<> struct Transforming<char> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<long> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<double> { using type = float; };

// T is a template template parameter
// It is a `class` template which has a single `class` template parameter
// Tuple is the tuple of types to transform
template<template<class> class T, class Tuple>
struct transform_types;

// Specialize for `std::tuple` to extract argument types
template<template<class> class T, class ... A>
struct transform_types<T, std::tuple<A...>>
{
    // Make a new `std::tuple` with the transformed types
    // Expand the parameter pack using the template class `T`
    using type = std::tuple<typename T<A>::type...>;
};

template<template<class> class T, class Tuple>
using transform_types_t = typename transform_types<T, Tuple>::type;

// Demonstration
using input_tuple = std::tuple<int, float, char, short, double, double>;
using transformed = transform_types_t<Transforming, input_tuple>;
using expected = std::tuple<int, float, int, short, float, float>;

#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_same_v<transformed, expected>);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a meta function like

```
template <template <typename> typename Transformer, typename... Ts> 
auto transform_types(std::tuple<Ts...>) -> std::tuple<typename Transformer<Ts>::type...>;
```

you can create a type trait like

```
template <template <typename> typename Transformer, typename Tuple>
using transform_types_t = decltype(transform_types<Transformer>(std::declval<Tuple>()));
```

and then you would use it like

```
using transformed_tuple = transform_types_t<Transforming, TUPLE>;
```

and now `transformed_tuple` is a `std::tuple<int, float, int, short int, float, float>`.  You can see it working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ca229e56e7e7fa2)

Comment: Be careful if the types are incomplete/not-object types. Wrapping the appropriate places in `type_identity<...>`(/`enable_if<true, ...>` before C++20) won't instantiate `tuple<Ts...>` or `tuple<Transformer<Ts>::type...>`: https://godbolt.org/z/9fG4K6Ys3

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ...> struct Transforming;
template<typename T> struct Transforming<T> { using type = T; };
template<> struct Transforming<char> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<long> { using type = int; };
template<> struct Transforming<double> { using type = float; };

template <template<typename...> class Transform,typename T>
struct Transformed;

template <template<typename...> class Transform,typename...Ts>
struct Transformed<Transform, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<typename Transform<Ts>::type ...>;
};


int main() {
    using t = std::tuple<char,long,double>;
    using transformed = Transformed<Transforming,t>::type;
    using expected = std::tuple<int,int,float>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< transformed,expected>;
}
```