# Is it legal to use function with no definition c++?

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

I've seen some snippet of code from this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of and have noticed this specific function template signature type:

```cpp
template<class F, class... Args>
static auto call(F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

Note: From the given implementation, there is no definition at all and only specifies its return type.

If this is possible, what are the possible applications that can be used for this?

Comment: Chances are, it was defined in a different file

Comment: What does the function do? Because, if there's no definition, then well, how would it work? That is like asking, "can a car work without an engine"?

Comment: I don't know but it specifies its return type

Comment: Is the function actually *used*? As in, the function template is instantiated and called or its address taken? Because otherwise it isn’t ODR-used, and doesn’t need to be defined.

Comment: This is the link i've seen it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of from the implementation of `std::invoke_result`

Comment: It should be defined in the same scope (i.e. in an included file maybe?), but from what I see this is just a forward declaration, and that's perfectly fine

Comment: But there is no definition at all

Comment: In your link, the possible implementation has been given!

Comment: `template <class> struct result_of;
template <class F, class... ArgTypes>
struct result_of<F(ArgTypes...)> : detail::invoke_result<void, F, ArgTypes...> {};` is a function that does nothing!

Comment: @DesmondGold So it’s just like my previous comment asks: the function is never actually called or otherwise ODR-used, so it doesn’t need to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed. `decltype` is an unevaluated context so the function isn't actually called, only it's return type is determined. Take [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) for example.  It is a function template declared by the standard and is only allowed to be used in an unevaluated expression as it may have no definition.

I like to call these types of function meta functions.  You can use them like type traits, or as helpers to build types for template code.  I used one in an answer the other day which was used to help convert a tuple of one type to another.  It looked like

```
template <template <typename> typename Transformer, typename... Ts> 
auto transform_types(std::tuple<Ts...>) -> std::tuple<typename Transformer<Ts>::type...>;
```

and I used it to build a type like

```
template <template <typename> typename Transformer, typename Tuple>
using transform_types_t = decltype(transform_types<Transformer>(std::declval<Tuple>()));
```

Here is a link to that post if you want to see the full example: [Transform the std::tuple types to another ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423250/transform-the-stdtuple-types-to-another-ones)

Comment: `std::declval` and the example `transform_types` **are not functions**. They are function **templates**.

Comment: and technically, if something has `{}` at the end (like in OP's example), it *is* the definition!

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him There is no `{}` in the Q that I can see.

Comment: Err, no, I mean in the cpp reference link OP has provided. Sorry! my bad :)

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him Where does `declval` have `{}` in the link?

Comment: @PeteBecker The doesn't really matter here.  As long as the function/function template is declared, it can be used in an unevaluated context.

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker