# How do I map a wrapper type over the types in a variant

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-templates

Suppose I have some code like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct wrapper {};

using my_variant = std::variant<int, bool>;

using my_wrapped = // should resolve to std::variant<wrapper<int>, wrapper<bool>>, by adding wrapper to each element of my_variant
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423250/transform-the-stdtuple-types-to-another-ones

Comment: @NathanOliver Didn't see that one, the solution is very similar agreed although it does differ a bit so I'm not sure whether it counts are a dupe

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with the help of template argument deduction:

```cpp
#include <variant>

template<template<typename...> class V, typename... Vargs>
struct map_inner {
    map_inner(const V<Vargs...>&){}

    template<template<typename> class Wrap>
    using type = V<Wrap<Vargs>...>;
};

template<template<typename...> class V, typename... Vargs>
map_inner<V, Vargs...> make_inner(const V<Vargs...>& v) {
    return map_inner<V, Vargs...>{v};
}

template<typename T>
struct my_wrapper {};

using my_variant = std::variant<int, bool>;

using my_wrapped_variant_cpp17 = typename decltype(map_inner{std::declval<my_variant>()})::type<my_wrapper>; // c++17 version

using my_wrapped_variant_cpp11 = typename decltype(make_inner(std::declval<my_variant>()))::type<my_wrapper>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::variant<my_wrapper<int>, my_wrapper<bool>>, my_wrapped_variant_cpp11>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::variant<my_wrapper<int>, my_wrapper<bool>>, my_wrapped_variant_cpp17>);
```

Note that the more c++17 version makes use of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to remove the need for a wrapper function to do the deduction for us.

This also works for types other than `std::variant`, such as `std::tuple`.

This code relies on c++17 fold expressions so I don't think it will work with c++11, although I've included a version that makes use of less c++17 concepts anyway