# How to transform int parameter pack

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Given a template

```
template <int... Ints>
struct FixedArray;
```

How to implement a meta function that multiplies each integer value by a given number?

```
template <int A, typename F>
struct Mul;

Mul<2, FixedArray<5, 7, 8>>::type
```

is the same as

```
FixedArray<10, 14, 16>
```

Comment: First, you need a specialization to get a grasp on the template parameters. Then, the  specialization simply needs to define a new type. Mission accomplished!

Comment: There are a couple techniques shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423250/transform-the-stdtuple-types-to-another-ones) that you could use to do this.

Comment: aside: `template <int... Ints> using FixedArray = std::integer_sequence<int, Ints...>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you can first define an empty `Mul` class:

```cpp
template<int A, typename T>
struct Mul;
```

Then create a specialization for `FixedArray`:

```cpp
template<int A, int ... Ints>
struct Mul<A, FixedArray<Ints...>>
{
    using type = FixedArray<(Ints * A)...>;
};
```

---

However, I'd rather have a typedef inside `FixedArray`, so the resulting syntax looks more natural to me:

```cpp
template <int ... Ints>
struct FixedArray
{
    template<int A>
    using Mul = FixedArray<(Ints * A)...>;
};

static_assert(std::same_as<FixedArray<1,2,3>::Mul<2>, FixedArray<2,4,6>>);
```