# C++: How to specify types inside a tuple based on types inside another tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, template-meta-programming

Say I have a tuple type e.g.

```
using Tuple1 = std::tuple<int, float, double>;
```

and some templated class

```
template <typename T>
class DummyClass;
```

and that I want to specify a tuple type that looks like this

```
using Tuple2 = std::tuple<DummyClass<std::tuple_element<0, Tuple1>::type>,
                          DummyClass<std::tuple_element<1, Tuple1>::type>,
                          DummyClass<std::tuple_element<2, Tuple1>::type>>;
```

Only now I'd like to make the above more generic and not have to manually unroll all the types in `Tuple2`. Is this achievable via template metaprogramming / variadic logic?

Comment: very related, maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423250/transform-the-stdtuple-types-to-another-ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this?

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


using t1=std::tuple<int,char,float>;

template <typename T>
struct S;

template<typename...Args>
std::tuple<S<Args> ...> maket2(const std::tuple<Args...>&);

template <typename T>
using t2 = decltype(maket2(std::declval<T>()));

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    t2<t1>, 
    std::tuple<S<int>, S<char>, S<float>>
>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K6KGKzo18
It uses the "classical" meta programming, maybe it can be also achieved using more contemporary constructs.